# Determine of the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:Determine if the described set is a subspace. If so, give proof. IF not, explain why not. Unless stated otherwise, a,b,c are real numbers.
The subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of the vectors of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} a\\ 0\\  b \end{bmatrix}$$ .

Okay so I know that in order for something to be a subspace it must contain the $\vec 0$, and that if $\vec u$ ,  $\vec v$ are in the subspace that   $\vec u$  + $\vec v$ must also be in the subspace, and if r is a real number and $\vec u$ is in S, the r$\vec u$ is also in S.

How do I go about turning the vectors I was given into something easier to work with? It doesn't make sense to just assume that the zero vector is in the given vector. How can I prove it?

Comment: if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ than they can be $0$ so the zero vector is clearly in the described subset.
what are your ideas for the other two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are told that the set is the set of all vectors $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ 0 \\ b \end{bmatrix}$.  To prove that is a subset of $R^3$, you need to prove
1) that this set is closed under vector addition and
2) that this set is closed under scalar multiplication.

To prove the first, take two vectors in the set, say, $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\ 0 \\ b_1\end{bmatrix}$, and, another, $\begin{bmatrix}a_2 \\ 0 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$.  What is the sum of those two vectors?  Is it also in that set?  That is, is it of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ 0 \\b\end{bmatrix}$ for some numbers, a and b?

To prove the second, take a genera vector in the set, $\begin{bmatrix}a \ 0 \ b\end{bmatrix} and a scalar (number), x.  What is the product of x and that vector?  Is it again in the same set?

Added as a comment on Emilio Novati's response- You **don't** need to prove that the subset contains the 0 vector or that it includes negatives.  Once you have shown that it is closed under scalar multiplication, you can get the 0 vector by multiplying any vector by 0 and you can get the negative of a given vector by multiplying the given vector by -1.

Comment: Thank you. I think what I was struggling with was my professor said something about just saying that you could pick it to have the zero vector and the way it was worded didn't sit well. It makes more sense seeing the $a_1$ and $a_2$ . I wasn't visualizing them that way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ the proof is simple. As you noted:

1)$\vec 0$ is in the subspace (chose $a=b=0$)

2) the opposite of $\vec v= [a,0,b]^T$ is $[-a,0,-b]^T$ that is in the subspace.

3) fore the sum $\vec v+ \vec w= [a,0,b]^T=[c,0,d]^T=[a+c,0,b+d]^T$ is in the subspace,

4) the product $k\vec v= k[a,0,b]^T= [ka,0,kb]^T$ is also in the subspace.